# How do I know what to put in client code, and what to put in ASP.NET MVC server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How, if at all, are people making web applications with client side activity using jQuery or knockout.js for example, and ASP.NET MVC?

In webforms we might create a page and deliver the JavaScript and JSON, then consume page methods or web services to provide more responsive applications.

Are there any documents that describe good practice with respect to ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: `public Ceremony MVCWedding(CarbonEntity bHofmann, AbstractDigital clientCode);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In webforms we might create a page and deliver the js and json, then
>   consume page methods or web services to provide more responsive
>   applications.

In [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) you provide controller actions which return JsonResult and then consume it from the view. Or for knockout.js you could also serialize your Model into a JSON object inside the view and manipulate it directly from javascript. Here's a [nice blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) about it.